# Connect python script running on App Engine to Oracle database

Tags: python, oracle, google-app-engine

Is it possible to connect a python script running on Google App Engine to a remote oracle database?.

Python needs cx_oracle library for the connection and cx_oracle library needs "oracle SQL client" installed in the server that script is running.

Thanks

Comment: If you use the new standard 2nd gen runtimes or GAE flex then you should be able to package the library of your choice, even those with C extensions.[GAE runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/appengine-generation)

Comment: To be pedantic, cx_Oracle 6 or 7 requires 'Oracle client libraries, version 11.2 or higher"